# I am looking to export webform submissions to cck instead of typing each submission in Drupal 6?

Tags: nodes, webforms

I have close to 150 submissions on my webform but had to change to content type midway , is there a simple way to export those submissions to a cck content type and map those fields instead of typing each one out.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You could try:
First [export the data](http://www.fortunesamerica.com/blog/export-drupal-6-webform-submitted-data-excel) to csv.

Then, import with [feeds](http://drupal.org/project/feeds).